# Given a list of values, generate a RegEx to match those values

Tags: regex

If you are given a list of values is it possible to generate a RegEx pattern that will match those values? I've seen some sites that allow you to generate a pattern to match a single string but haven't found anything that will accept multiple inputs.

The only way I can think to do it would be to split the values up by character, eliminate duplicates and use that list in brackets for a character group but that seems cumbersome and I'm not sure how well that would cover special characters.

Example:

Values: abcd,abce,abcf,accd,adcd,aecd

RegEx would be \a[b-e]c[d-f]\

EDIT: Further information to hopefully avoid the XY problem Lucas mentioned below.

We are receiving inputs of serial number and model pairs and are doing QA to determine if the pair is valid. The current method is that we have a list of serial numbers grouped by the model of the device and are currently using a regular expression based on the serial numbers of each specific model to do the QA. Right now the reg ex is being created manually.

Comment: Easiest would just be joining the lines with the alternation operator (`|`), e.g. `abcd|abce|abcf|accd|adcd|aecd`

Comment: Of course it's possible.  Trivially ... `/abcd|abce|abcf|accd|adcd|aecd/`.  I think you're asking if it's possible to create efficient and/or more compact regexes, no?

Comment: Thats correct. The list would be ~1000 values so just joining them with or wouldnt be too practical.

Comment: Looks like you've got an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here

Comment: That's a fair point. I'll update the original with information about what I am trying to accomplish rather than the way I am going about it.

Comment: There is a cool website that can do this sort of well. Basically you create "sample sets" of data, highlight what should match, then it generates the RegEx for you. Source code is available too. Look here: http://regex.inginf.units.it/

Comment: That is a very interesting website that might solve this problem. I don't quite follow the data requirements but I think playing around with this might work. It also suggests that what I was asking might be fairly difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of acceptable serials by model:

```
models:
  $model1: [1##,2##,3##,4##]
  $model2: [5##,643,7##,8##]
```

You get a serial and model, and then test if the serial is in that particular model.:

```
$model=$model1, $serial=643
```

You would make a function that handles it programatically:

```
validate ->
  if $serial in models[$model]
    return True
  return False
```

Where is the regex? You don't need a regex for this.

Comment: The reason for using regex is that we want to be able to test serial numbers that aren't already in the list. As we add new equipment of the same model we want to test the serial numbers to see if they are likely valid in the hopes of combating input errors.

Comment: I know I am not understanding you perfectly. But if they do belong in a range, ie 600 - 699, regex still isn't how I would solve it. I would store these ranges in replacement of the static values, and do similar operations.

Comment: Many of the serial numbers are mixed letters and numbers like this 796KTV1 so I don't know that a strict range would work, though that seems to be along the track we are going. Is there a way to do the ranges to include alphabetical characters as well?